# I've lost my passport and residence permit while staying in Austria. What are my next steps?

Tags: visa, passport, austria, residence-cards

This is a copy of the same question I asked on the travel forum and there they asked me to ask about it here.

I am an Indian student residing in Italy, my girlfriend is also a student from India residing in Vienna, today her wallet containing her passport (with visa) and residence permit were stolen.

We promptly filed a report at the local police station, where the police office told us that the report is enough for travelling to Vienna (she left today).

I printed out the last and front pages of the passport as well as the the visa and attached them to the report, hoping that will be enough for her return trip.

I understand from previous posts that the Embassy at Vienna will issue her a temporary passport.

But I am a bit scared, as she has no other documents with her. Not even the residence permit. How would she go about regenerating everything?

For now we decided that she will go to the local police station in vienna and file another report before proceeding to the embassy for a temporary passport.

But what happens from there?

Comment: You are traveling to Vienna to obtain a temporary passport from the Indian Embassy, is that correct?  Your girlfriend will presumably also need to apply for a replacement residence permit.  Are you asking about the steps necessary to do that, or about whether there are other things she will need to do in addition to that?

Comment: I am asking about the steps necessary to do it and if she will need to do some other things as well.... Or maybe if there's a possibility that they may kick her out of the country....

Comment: She's not going to be kicked out of the country.  She has the police report and the copies of the stolen documents, which she is obviously moving promptly to replace.  Here's the scoop on lost and stolen Austrian residence permits: http://www.auslaender.at/verlust-oder-diebstahl-des-identitatsausweises.  Short translation, just as she's doing: foreign police report, Austrian police report, apply to issuing office for replacement.

Comment: Thank you so much for that link, it helps a lot! Is it possble for you post that as an answer?

Comment: I hesitate to do so because it seems not to be an official source and I am not personally familiar with the process or with the Austrian system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Austrian government’s [information for foreign citizens: Social Affairs and Emergencies](https://www.help.gv.at/Portal.Node/hlpd/public/content/154/Seite.1540000.html) can help guide you, but you’ve already ticked off all the boxes, and more:

- Filed a police report
- Reported your passport to your country’s consulate
- Received a replacement passport (and, best case scenario, you had a copy with all the details)

Now, deal with the residence permit. Hopefully, you kept a copy of your confirmation of registration (Meldebestätigung), which you got when you registered at [Meldeamt](https://oead.at/fileadmin/Dokumente/oead.at/KIM/Nach_Oesterreich/Einreise_und_Aufenthalt/Inlandsbehoerden_en.pdf) closest to your residence. Take that, if you have it, your police report, and your replacement passport.